# Vuex getter wasn't updated after store mutation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, getter

I've created app using VueJS and Vuex. 
This code is used in store:

```js
const separateArticle = {
  state: {article: {}},
  mutations: {
    LOAD_ARTICLE(state, id) {
      fetch(`http://localhost:3000/articles/${id}`, { mode: "cors" })
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(response => {
          state.article = response;})}
  },
  actions: {
    loadSeparateArticle({ commit }, id) {commit("LOAD_ARTICLE", id);}
  },
  getters: { articleData(state) {return state.article;} }
};
```

component code :

```js
<template>
 <div>
   <img src="articleData.imgSrc"/>
    <Article v-bind:article = "articleData" v-bind:key="articleData._id"></Article>
  <div>
    Comments
  </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import Article from "./Article.vue";

export default {
  props: ["article"],
  name: "ArticleDetail",
  components: {
    Article
  },
  data() {
    return { articleData: this.$store.getters.articleData };
  },
  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch("loadSeparateArticle", this.$route.params._id);
  }
};
</script>
```

When the component is created getter is triggered, but after store modification, it wasn't called. Vue doesn't understand that store is updated.

How can I manage this issue?

Comment: Why would you create a getter for a state variable if you aren't doing anything with it? And your problem is probably related to the fact that you return your getter inside of `data()` instead of `computed`. https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html

Comment: State modification and another state attributes will be added soon, so it's good to have the separate getter.

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot!